# Can't blur ComboboxInput from Headless UI in Vue3, Composition API

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, headless-ui

I'm trying to access `<ComboboxInput/>` through ref and programmatically blur the input element. The error I get is that blur is undefined but when I console.log the ref itself it seems like an actual ref to HTMLInputElement.

Here is the ComboboxInput:

```
  <ComboboxInput
    class="border-none pl-3 pr-10 leading-5 text-gray-900"
    v-bind="{ ...$attrs, ...rest }"
    :class="[autocomplete({ size }), { [readonlyStyle]: readonly }]"
    :display-value="() => getSelectedValues(value)"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    @change="onChange"
    @focus="openOptions"
    :ref="comboInput"
   />
```

And here is the ref:

```
const comboInput = ref()
const handleBlur = () => {
  comboInput.value?.blur()
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

you don't bind [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html).  Use `ref=` not `:ref=`

```html
<ComboboxInput
  ref="comboInput"
/>
```

Then with headlessui the inner input element is accessed with `.el` or `.$el`, so to blur:

```js
comboInput.value.$el.blur()
```

Comment: Thanks! I worked but only with setTimeout, do you know why is that?

Comment: You've not shown how handleBlur is called so I'm not sure.  A more detailed code snippet might be needed.  There might be some other action interfering and reestablishing focus.  What is the value of the ref without setTimeout?  Is the method being called after the component is fully mounted?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using a setTimeout in this case, use something like this

```
import { ref, nextTick } from 'vue'

const comboInput = ref()

const handleBlur = () => {

nextTick(() => {
     comboInput.value.$el.blur()
  })

}
```

This should work